# Another plausible inequality.

Tags: inequalities

I come across the following problem in my study.

Consider in the real field. Let $ 0\le x\le1 $, $a_1^2+a_2^2=b_1^2+b_2^2=1$.Is it true

$ (a_1b_1+xa_2b_2)^2\le\left(\frac{(1-x)+(1+x)(a_1b_1+a_2b_2)}{(1+x)+(1-x)(a_1b_1+a_2b_2)}\right)^{2}(a_1^2+xa_{2}^{2})(b_1^2+xb_{2}^{2})$?

Comment: Something is wrong with your inequality: when I substitute $x=0$ it implies $a_1b_1\le(a_1b_1)^2$, while the opposite inequality holds.

Comment: Hi miwalin, 
I think you need, modify the inequality a little bit. 
Because if we take $x=1$, we would get that 
$(a_1b_1+a_2b_2)\leq (a_1b_1+a_2b_2)^2.$
But choosing vectors $(a_1,a_2)$  and $(b_1,b_2)$ in the unit circle, such that the angle between them is close to $\frac{\pi}{2}$, we see that the inequality is not hold in general.

Comment: I modified it. Thank you for pointing out my typos.

Comment: Your older question has the exact same title: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/20172/a-plausible-inequality.  This will make it difficult for people to browse questions in the future.

Comment: title changed from
"A Plausible Inequality"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Can Hang points out in his response, the inequality does not hold in general. Thanks to his comment to my own post, I stand corrected and claim the inequality is valid at least for the case
$$
a_1b_1+xa_2b_2\ge0
\qquad(*)
$$
(and this seems to be a necessary condition as well).

Let me do some standard things. First let
$$
a_1=\frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}, \quad
a_2=\frac{2u}{1+u^2}, \quad
b_1=\frac{1-v^2}{1+v^2}, \quad
b_2=\frac{2v}{1+v^2}
$$
where $uv\ge0$.
Substitution reduces the inequality to the following one:
$$
((1-u^2)(1-v^2)+4xuv)^2
\le\biggl(\frac{(uv+1)^2-x(u-v)^2}{(uv+1)^2+x(u-v)^2}\biggr)^2
((1-u^2)^2+4xu^2)((1-v^2)^2+4xv^2).
\qquad{(1)}
$$
Now introduce the notation
$$
A=(1-u^2)(1-v^2)+4xuv, \quad
B=(uv+1)^2, \quad C=x(u-v)^2
$$
and note that $A,B,C$ are nonnegative; the inequality $A\ge0$ is equivalent to the above condition $(*)$. In addition,
$$
A\le B-C
\qquad{(2)}
$$
because
$$
B-C-A=(1-x)(u+v)^2\ge0.
$$
In the new notation the inequality (1) can be written more compact:
$$
A^2(B+C)^2\le(B-C)^2(A^2+4BC)
$$
which after straightforward reduction becomes
$$
A^2\le(B-C)^2,
$$
while the latter follows from (2).

Comment: $A$ is not necessarily nonnegative. For example, $x=1,u=1,v=-1$. 

Comment: Oh-oh, you were very careful in checking. I'll fix when I have time. But why do you expect from me a cleaned solution?!

Comment: I found, by accidently, that your proof relies on the nonnegativity of $A$. I just point out for you. 

Comment: You know now that the inequality does not work in general, but a tiny (natural! see the second post) condition insures that it holds.

Comment: I think there is a mistake in your solution, dear Wadim Zudilin. The inequality $A \ge 0$ is false. Please check the case when $x=0,$ $u=\frac{1}{2}$ and $v=2.$

By the way, I think the inequality also does not hold for $a_2 b_2 \ge 0,$ but it holds for $a_1b_1+a_2b_2 \ge 0.$ We can modify my solution below a little to obtain this conclusion.

Comment: @Can Hang: Your solution is essentially the same one, so it could be modified to get the same condition $a_1b_1+xa_2b_2\ge0$. I could have put this condition at the very beginning but I did not realise at that time that $A$ can be negative and there are counter examples in this case. So I (and hopefully Lin as well) thank you for figuring out the correct form of the "plausible inequality".

Comment: Yes, with the discussion by you both, I realize the inequality holds only if $a_1b_1+xa_2b_2\ge0$. However, this condition is strange. The ideal additional condition is $a_1b_1+a_2b_2\ge0$, unfortunately, this is not true (it is not difficult to find a counterexample). It is now the right time to end this discussion. 

Comment: The condition is probably not too strange: your inequality is for the scalar product of two vectors, $(a_1,\sqrt{x}a_2)$ and $(b_1,\sqrt{x}b_2)$. The angle between them should be cute. I am still curious about some "geometric" proof of the inequality.

Answer (score 4):

I think your inequality is false, dear miwalin. Please check the case when $a_1=b_2=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and $a_2=b_1=-\frac{1}{2}.$ But I think **it is true when $a_1,$ $a_2,$ $b_1,$ $b_2$ are nonnegative numbers.**

Let me prove it in the case $a_1,$ $a_2,$ $b_1,$ $b_2$ are nonnegative real numbers. Write the inequality as
$$\frac{(a_1^2+xa_2^2)(b_1^2+xb_2^2)}{(a_1b_1+xa_2b_2)^2} -1 \ge \left[ \frac{(1+x)+(1-x)(a_1b_1+a_2b_2)}{(1-x)+(1+x)(a_1b_1+a_2b_2)}\right]^2-1.$$
Since 
$$(a_1^2+xa_2^2)(b_1^2+xb_2^2)-(a_1b_1+xa_2b_2)^2=x(a_1^2b_2^2+a_2^2b_1^2-2a_1a_2b_1b_2)= x[(a_1^2+a_2^2)(b_1^2+b_2^2)-(a_1b_1+a_2b_2)^2]= x[1-(a_1b_1+a_2b_2)^2]$$
and
$$\left[ \frac{(1+x)+(1-x)(a_1b_1+a_2b_2)}{(1-x)+(1+x)(a_1b_1+a_2b_2)}\right]^2-1=\frac{4x[1-(a_1b_1+a_2b_2)^2]}{[(1-x)+(1+x)(a_1b_1+a_2b_2)]^2},$$
the above inequality is equivalent to (notice that $x[1-(a_1b_1+a_2b_2)^2] \ge 0$)
$$[(1-x)+(1+x)(a_1b_1+a_2b_2)]^2 \ge 4(a_1b_1+xa_2b_2)^2,$$
or
$$(1-x)+(1+x)(a_1b_1+a_2b_2) \ge 2(a_1b_1+xa_2b_2),$$
or
$$(1-x)(1-a_1b_1+a_2b_2) \ge 0,$$
which is obvious.

Comment: What you take the value of $x$?

Comment: After taking my values of $a_1,$ $a_2,$ $b_1,$ $b_2,$ the inequality is false for all $0<x<1.$

Comment: @Can Hang: +1. Thanks for figuring out an explicit counter example. The inequality is true for $a_2b_2>0$. 

Comment: Well, your assistance is extremely helpful. Thank you! The correct condition is $a_1b_1+xa_2b_2\ge0$.